# Position div offscreen?

Tags: css

I have a div, and I wish to position it offscreen, at the bottom - I will then animate it in via jquery.

Bottom 0 just aligns it to the bottom of the screen but how can I get it offscreen?

Answer (score 1):

just use margin-top: 100%;
If you put it inside body then, it will use margin-top: 100% on the body, so it all falls out of the body. If you use overflow:hidden on body then it will work out fine i guess.

So your css looks like this:

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#otheritem{
    margin-top: 100%
}
```

That's a lot of body-text.

It might as well be html in stead of body.
I'm not sure.

Comment: This does not work. It hides all of my pages content.

Comment: can you maybe put some of your code in jsfiddle or give me a link to somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it just hidding the element with: `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`. or, you can set `bottom: -100%;` inside of a element with `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Thanks, how would I then animate this? $('#file-upload').animate({'top': '50px'}, 1000); This animates it in from the top, not the bottom.